# pyinstaller not finding my program

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm unable to get PyInstaller to find  my program. I have tried to but still can't get it to work.

Could somebody tell me how to use PyInstaller or link me to a simple tutorial that doesn't say things like 'run this' without telling you where it is.

I have gotten as far as telling PyInstaller where my program is in the command prompt, but it can't find it.

```
 """
VERSION 0.1
TIDE
CREATOR: THEDUDXO / ISAAC BOON
"""

from Tkinter import *

food_storage = 100
height = 1
tide = 0
food = 100
population = 50
crabfarms = 1
pop_rise = 0
food_rise = 50
clay_income = population/5
clay = 1
tide_rise = 1
stat = '[ height:  ' +str(height)+' ]  [ tide:  '+str(tide)+' ]  [ food:  '+ str(food) +'/'+str(food_storage)+']  [  food rise:  '+str(food_rise)+' ]  [ population:  '+ str(population)+ ' ]  [ clay:  '+ str(clay)+']   [ Clay Income:  '+str(clay_income)+' ]'

def update_stat():
    global stat, stats
    stat = '[ height:  ' +str(height)+' ]  [ tide:  '+str(tide)+' ]  [ food:  '+ str(food) +'/'+str(food_storage)+']  [  food rise:  '+str(food_rise)+' ]  [ population:  '+ str(population)+ ' ]  [ clay:  '+ str(clay)+']   [ Clay Income:  '+str(clay_income)+' ]'
    stats.config(text=stat)
    print 'update_stat taceback' ,stat

def crabfarm():
    global crabfarms,clay,food_rise,Hhelp
    if clay >= 5:
        crabfarms +=1                    # $$$ note to self - Make crabfarms cost more clay each build, without it being buggy? $$$ #
        food_rise += 15
        clay = clay - 5
        print 'crabfarm check'
    else:
        Hhelp.config(text = 'Not enougth clay.')
    print 'crabfarm traceback'
    update_stat()


def granary():
    print 'granary trace'
    global food_storage,clay,Hhelp
    if clay > 4:
        print 'granary trace sucsess'
        food_storage += 10
        print clay
        clay = clay -5
    else:
        Hhelp.config(text = 'Not enougth clay.')
    update_stat()

def turn_end():
    global height, clay, stat, tide_rise, tide,population,pop_rise,food,food_rise,clay_income,game

    Hhelp.config(text='Turn ended.')

    previous_height = height
    height += clay
    clay = 0

    previous_clay = clay
    clay += clay_income

    tide += tide_rise
    tide_rise += 0.5

    pop_rise = int(population/26)

    population += pop_rise
    clay_income = int(population/5)

    food = (food - population)+food_rise
    food = min(food,food_storage)

    if clay <= 0:
        clay = 0

    if height < tide:
        Hhelp.config(text = 'Your civilization drowned!')
        end_turn.destroy()
        population = 0

    if food < 0:
        food = 0
        clay = previous_clay
    print 'endturn traceback' , stat
    update_stat()

def exit_game():
    global game
    game.destroy()
    print 'quit traceback'
    #save feature here? (add load as a seprate button prehaps in main menu)

def farm_menu():
    def Exit():
        farm.destroy()


    farm = Tk()

    frame=Frame(farm,background='grey',border='3')
    frame.pack()

    build_farm = Button(frame,text='Build a Crabfarm (5 clay)',command = crabfarm)
    build_granary = Button(frame,text='Build a Granary (5 clay)',command=granary)
    done=Button(frame,text='done',command=Exit)

    build_farm.pack(side='top')
    build_granary.pack(side='top')
    done.pack()

    farm.mainloop()

game = Tk()


frame1=Frame(background='blue',border = '3')
frame = Frame(background='grey',border='10')
frame2 = Frame(background='black',border ='5')
frame3 = Frame(background = 'orange',border='3')

frame1.pack(side='top')
frame.pack(side='left')
frame2.pack(side='right')
frame3.pack()



stats = Label(frame1,text=stat)

stats.pack()



end_turn = Button(frame2,text='End turn', command = turn_end)
Qquit= Button(frame2,text='Quit',command = exit_game,background='red')

Qquit.pack(side='right')
end_turn.pack(side='left')



Hhelp = Label(frame3,background = 'grey',text = 'Welcome to Tide! version; 0.1')

Hhelp.pack()


farms=Button(frame,text='Build Farms',command = farm_menu)

farms.pack()



game.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure what you mean ... pyinstaller is very easy to use . here is step by step

1. download pyinstaller from http://www.pyinstaller.org/ (the zip version)
2. extract it to C:\ , you should now have a path like `C:\pyinstaller-2.1\<bunchafiles>`
3. go to your source folder where you normally run your program
4. hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>RIGHTCLICK</kbd> select "open command window here"
5. you should now be at a command prompt `C:\path\to\code> _`
6. type: `python C:\pyinstaller-2.1\pyinstaller.py --onefile my_main_prog.py`
7. run exe that is gernerated ...

I went ahead and copied and pasted your code into a file `c:\py_exp\tk_stackoverflow_thedudxo.py`
I opened a console and entered the following commands

```
cd c:\py_exp
python c:\pyinstaller\pyinstaller.py --onefile --console tk_stackoverflow_thedudxo.py
```

I now have a new file located at `c:\py_exp\dist\tk_stackoverflow_thedudxo.py`

if I double click this executable(or run it from the console/terminal/cmd.exe) your program pops right up ...

Comment: If you run it from the console you should see an error message

Comment: Run what, the exe or pyinstaller?

Comment: the exe ... (or pyinstaller if thats where the error is...(eg no program is created))

Comment: Can you put your source up(virgin or just a link to a zip)? Without seeing it i cant help much .. I have used pyinstaller a  bunch with no problems exactly as I detailed above.... What Python version do you have

Comment: 2.7. theres not much to see, it just comes up with what looks like the command promt but it dosnt do anything.

Comment: well without seeing it I cant help you much more than I have above ... if your source doesnt do anything im not sure what you expected the exe to do ... you might need to add the --console flag to the pyinstaller arguments

Comment: wait, by scource do you mean my actual code for the program? how does that effect anything?

Comment: ...yes of coarse thats what source means ... because every time ive done that command on my programs it works... so I would need an example of code that does not work that way in order to have any hope of telling you why it wont do that ...

Comment: that built no problem for me(see my edit to answer) ... I copied and pasted it verbatim... what version of python are you using? when you run the `pyinstaller.py` command, on the 10th line or something it says what python it is using .. make sure thats the same python that you normally use

Comment: i told you, i use 2.7